# Hyperref marks lastpage as a reference

Tags: hyperref, fancyhdr, lastpage

I am using the  hyperref package, lastpage package and fancyhdr package. My problem is, that the number showing the amount of total pages (in the footer) is red and works like a link to the front page. I do not want it to be neither red or work as a link, though I want to link to the sections in my table of contents (which works perfectly).
Please help! :-)

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{article}         
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
        \fancyhead[LO,LE]{Author}
        \fancyhead[RO,RE]{Document title}
        \fancyfoot[CO, CE]{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    linktoc=section,
    colorlinks=true
}


\begin{document}


\thispagestyle{empty}

\vspace*{3cm}
\noindent \rule{\linewidth}{3pt}
\vspace{0.2cm}
\begin{center}\textbf{\Huge{Title}}\end{center}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\rule{\linewidth}{3pt}

\vspace{3cm}

\newpage


\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{First section} \label{sec:1}


\section{Second section}

This is a reference to \nameref{sec:1}.


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please post a MWE (minimum working example) to show what you've done so far. In particular, it would be useful if you showed how you've made use of the commands of the `fancyhdr` package to affect the page number display

Comment: Sorry, forgot that! :-) -- Think i posted the code wrong too.. :/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `hyperref` package provides the variant commands `\ref*` and `\pageref*` in case one needs to avoid the creation of a hyperlink while creating a cross-reference.

Thus, if you write

```
\fancyfoot[CO, CE]{Page \thepage\ of \pageref*{LastPage}
```

you'll achieve your objective.

Comment: That's exactly it! Thank you so much, I knew it was quite simple :-)

Comment: @Gabriel - I'm glad you found this answer useful. Do note that that there's something odd about the Table of Contents page being numbered "Page i of 1". You may want to look into what the `pagesLTS` package can do for you to keep track of the *total* number of pages of a piece, be they numbered in roman or arabic. Or, consider moving the `\pagestyle{fancy}` directive *after* the `\pagenumbering{arabic}` statement.

Comment: Hmmm you may have a point.. My idea was however to do it like the document found here: http://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf. The author enumerates the "table of content"-pages with roman numerals too. In this way only the important pages are enumerated with arabic numerals, and only these pages count in the amount of total pages :-)

Comment: @Gabriel - You noticed correctly that Tobi Oetiker's "Short Guide" has different numbering styles for the front matter and the main matter of the document. However, that document doesn't use a "Page x of y" display method...

Comment: You're right, I'll check it out, thanks alot! :)