# LastPage not working with HyperRef

Tags: hyperref

I'm trying to use hyperref to enable clickable content in my toc.

My main file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\includegraphics[height=0.8cm,width=0.75\linewidth]{image/logo}}
\fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage \ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\title{Report}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\pagestyle{fancy}

\include{PartA}

\end{document}
```

But i'm getting an error:

```
File        | Type   | Line   | Message

Report.tex  | Error | line 60 | !Argument of Hy@setref@link has an extra }. <inserted text>\par \include{PartA}

Report.tex  | Error | line 60 | !Paragraph ended before \Hy@setref@link was complete. <to be read again>\par \include{PartA}

Report.tex  | Error | line 60 | !Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.

etc...
```

If i comment the

```
\pageref{LastPage}
```

The report compiles and works ok.

```
\fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage \ of } %\pageref{LastPage}}
```

So i don't know why lastpage doesn't work with hyperref. Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Your posted code works for me.  So perhaps something else in your PartA is triggering the problem.

Comment: Could you please use a package for blind text, such as `lipsum` or `kantlipsum` to produce several pages with text? (instead of `\include{...}`-ing something we don't have.) If I do so, your example works for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had also problems using `hyperref` and `lastpage`. The error

`` ...
LaTeX Warning: Reference `LastPage' on page 2 undefined on input line 12. ``

My `rhead` looked like this 

`\rhead{\footnotesize \thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}`

I stumbled over this question [Hyperref marks lastpage as a reference](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102533/hyperref-marks-lastpage-as-a-reference) and the used the same solution, i.e.
replacing `\pageref` with `\pageref*`.

`\rhead{\footnotesize \thepage/\pageref*{LastPage}}`

works!