# Colored footer with \pagref fails (page x of y)

Tags: fancyhdr, lastpage

I use the package `fancyhdr` together with `lastpage`. When I change the color of the footer with

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,naustrian]{article}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=4.3cm, bottom=2cm, headheight=2.3cm]{geometry} % for margins on a A4paper
\usepackage[dvipsnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{luacolor,lua-ul} %for usage of style attributes - background color
% color of footer
\definecolor{footerColor}{HTML}{800000}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}} % set the \leftmark
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{{\textcolor{footerColor}{Seite \thepage\ von \pageref{LastPage}}}}

\usepackage[pdfa, unicode]{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks={true},
    linkcolor={black},
    urlcolor={blue},
    linktoc={all},
}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\kant[1-10]
\end{document}
```

then I get the following result:

[image]

The `\pageref` isn't colored. Any idea how to color the total amount of pages?

As far as I can see it has to do with the `hyperref` package but I'm unclear how to change it to have it working properly. (using `livetex 2021 with lualatex 1.13.2`)

Comment: make a complete example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with `hyperref`. It makes the `\pageref{LastPage}` into a clickable link, which you have declared as being black. You can use `\pageref*{LastPage}` instead to not make it into a link.

(Inspired by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102540/113546))

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,naustrian]{article}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=4.3cm, bottom=2cm, headheight=2.3cm]{geometry} % for margins on a A4paper
\usepackage[dvipsnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{luacolor,lua-ul} %for usage of style attributes - background color
% color of footer
\definecolor{footerColor}{HTML}{800000}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}} % set the \leftmark
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{{\textcolor{footerColor}{Seite \thepage\ von \pageref*{LastPage}}}}

\usepackage[pdfa, unicode]{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks={true},
    linkcolor={black},
    urlcolor={blue},
    linktoc={all},
}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\kant[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well... The answer I have seen but I didn't think it might be of relevance :-/ Thx for spotting the error :-)

Answer (score 2):

There must be something wrong with your code, look below:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}  
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\definecolor{footerColor}{HTML}{800000}
\fancyfoot[C]{{\textcolor{footerColor}{Seite \thepage\ von \pageref{LastPage}}}}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}

test

\end{document}
```